# Why my android foreground service has been killed automatically in some Device like (Vivo,Oppo,Mi,Oneplus) after 5 minutes

Tags: java, android, service, location, foreground

I create background and foreground service both to get android location on every Interval and send it to server.

When App is in foreground at that time service run fine but when app is in background my foreground service notification display perfect for few minutes after some time it automatically killed my service and I am not getting any location update after that.

It runs fine in Samsung device but create issue in Oppo,Vivo, Mi and OnePlus device

So please help me out to find best way to run Location service when app is closed, background or foreground in any state in all device and Android version greater Than "O"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Even foreground services can be killed.  You cannot write your apps assuming anything will last forever.  Rethink how often and when you actually need background location updates.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you so much for your reply. I want location update on every interval to track my employee location for their field work functionality. I need to start service when Job hours start and stop service when Job Hours complete next day when employee open App at that time service should start.